Showing equivalence between two definitions for Maximal ideals
Background:
Definition 1:
Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an ideal of $R$.  Then $M$ is called a maximal ideal of $R$ if $M\neq R$ and there does not exist any ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $M\subset I\subset R$.
Definition 2:
Given a ring $R$ and a proper ideal $M$ of $R$, $M$ is a maxial ideal of $R$ if for any ideal $I$ with $M\subset I$, either $M=I$ or $I=R$.
Question:
I am trying to show that Definition 1 and Definition 2 are equal in symbolic logic notation.
For Definition 1
the statement "if $M\neq R$ and there does not exist any ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $M\subset I\subset R$." be symbolize as
$$M\neq R \wedge \sim((\exists I \subset R)(M\subset I\subset R))$$ which further symbolizes to
$$(M\to R)\wedge (\sim(R\to M)) \wedge (\forall I)\sim((M\to I)\to R))$$ which again further symbolizes to
$$(\forall I)((M\to R)\wedge (\sim(R\to M)) \wedge \sim((M\to I)\to R)))\quad (1)$$
For Definition 2
The statement "Given a ring $R$ and a proper ideal $M$ of $R$, if for any ideal $I$ with $M\subset I $, either $M=I$ or $I=R$." should be symbolize as:
$$(M\subset R)\wedge \forall I((M\subset I))\to (M=I \vee I=R))$$ which further symbolizes to
$$\forall I((M\to R)\wedge(((M\to  I))\to ((M\to I\wedge I\to M) \vee (I\to R \wedge R\to I))))\quad (2)$$
I know that Definition 1 is supppose to equal to Definition 2 expressed in negation form.
I am having trouble showing statement $(1)$ equals statement $(2)$ using equivalence laws in sentential logic.  I am actually not sure if i got the symbolization correctly also.
Thank you in advance

Definition 1 is using the symbol $\subset$ to mean "proper inclusion". Definition 2 is using the symbol to mean "subset of", not necessarily proper.  If you are going to try to show equivalence, then you should replace the first definition with "$M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$", or the second definition with "$M\subseteq I\subseteq R$."

@Arturo Magidin $M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ is equvialent to $\sim((M\to I)\to R)$?  Also $M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ should be a negation of $M=I\vee I=R$.  Because if so, I don't know how to show that $\sim((M\to I)\to R)$ is equivalent to $\sim((M=I)\vee (I=R))$

I have no idea what you think you mean by "$M\to I$". Those are not symbols I generally use when talking about ideals.  No, $M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ is not the negation (statements have only one negation, not multiple ones, so talking about "a  negation" of a statement is silly) of $M=I\vee I=R$; the negation of $M=I\vee I=R$ is $M\neq I\wedge I\neq R$. It does not make any assertions about inclusions. $M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ means exactly what it says and nothing more: that $M\subseteq I$, and $M\neq I$, and $I\subseteq R$ and $I\neq R$.

@ArturoMagidindon't $M\subsetneq I$ is equivalent to $(M\subset I)\wedge \sim(I\subset M)$, and so $M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ would be equivalent to $(M\subset I)\wedge \sim(I\subset M)\wedge (I\subset R)\wedge \sim(R\subset I)$?  Also in your first comment, I should replace $(1)$ with $(M\neq R \wedge \sim((\exists I \subset R)(M\subsetneq I\subsetneq R))$ and for $(2)$ it should be $(M\subset I\subset R)\wedge \forall I((M\subset I))\to (M=I \vee I=R))$?

For the second time: Your post uses $\subset$ to mean two different things. Until you specify which one you want the symbol to actually mean, anything you write is impossible to decypher, and I see no reason to spend time attempting to do so.

@ArturoMagidin I use $\subset$ to mean subset and $\subsetneq$ to mean proper subset.

@ArturoMagidin I am guessing that $A\neq B$ to mean the same as $A\subsetneq B$ or $B\subsetneq A$.  I rarely use $\subsetneq$ notation, and I am not familar with the proper notational convention.  Oftentimes, when I see set $A$ is a proper subset of set $B$, i often interpret it to mean either $A\neq B$ or $A\subset B$ and $B\not\subset A$. Sorry if my notations are confusing.  I did not know $\subset$ could have ambiguity in meaning.

No, $A\neq B$ means $A$ is different from $B$. It does not mean "$A$ is a proper subset of $B$ or $B$ is a proper subset of $A$" Why would it mean that? Are you not familiar with the notion of two sets that are neither contained in the other? Really?

@ArturoMagidin i meant $A\neq B$ to mean $A\not\subset B$ or $B\not\subset A$.  Sorry it was a typo.  Can you give the proper corrections to what my statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ should be please.

Your "Background" runs into the serious difficulty that your two definitions use the same symbol to mean different things.

Definition 1 is using the symbol $\subset$ to mean "proper inclusion". That is,
$$\begin{align*}
A\subset B&\iff (\forall x(x\in A\to x\in B))\wedge (\exists y(y\in B\wedge y\notin A))\\
&\iff A\subseteq B\wedge A\neq B.
\end{align*}$$
It says: "An ideal $M$ is maximal if and only if $M\neq R$, and there does not exist an ideal $I$ that is strictly between $M$ and $R$, $M\subseteq I\subseteq R$, with $M\neq I$ and $I\neq R$.

Definition 2 is using the symbol $\subset$ to mean "inclusion". That is, in Definition 2 the symbol means
$$
A\subset B\iff \forall x (x\in A\implies x\in B).$$
That is: a proper ideal $M$ (i.e., $M\neq R$) is maximal if and only if whenever it is contained in an ideal $I$, then either $M=I$ or $I=R$.


Because the two definitions are using the same symbol to mean different things (and because for some reason you are using $\to$ between two ideals, a symbol that is not used to mean anything about ideals) you are tying yourself into your usual knots.
Here is how to write both definitions using the same symbol. I will use $\subseteq$ to means "subset, not necessarily proper". That is, $A\subseteq B$ means $\forall x (x\in A\to x\in B)$.

Definition 1. Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an ideal of $R$. Then $M$ is maximal if and only if (1) $M\neq R$; and (2) there does not exist an ideal $I$ such that (i) $M\subseteq I\subseteq R$; and (ii) $M\neq I$; and (iii) $I\neq R$.
Definition 2. Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an ideal of $R$ with $M\neq R$. Then $M$ is maximal if and only if for every ideal $I$ of $R$, if $M\subseteq I\subseteq R$, then $M=I$ or $I=R$.

The equivalence should now be clear. Definition 2 is, symbolically,
$$\Bigl((M\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\neq R)\Bigr)\wedge\Bigl( \forall I\bigl( (I\triangleleft R\wedge M\subseteq I)\to (M=I\vee I=R)\bigr)\Bigr)$$
while Definition 1 is, symbolically
$$\Bigl((M\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\neq R)\Bigr)\wedge \Bigl( \neg\exists I\bigl((I\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\subseteq I)\wedge (M\neq I)\wedge (I\neq R)\bigr)\Bigr).$$
The equivalence now follows from the following equivalences for nonempty domains of discourse:

$\neg\exists x(P(x))\equiv \forall x(\neg P(x))$. Therefore, third clause of definition 1 is equivalent to
$$\forall I \Bigl( \neg(I\triangleleft R)\vee \neg (M\subseteq I)\vee \neg (M\neq I)\vee \neg(I\neq R)\Bigr).$$
$\neg P \wedge Q$ is equivalent to $P\to Q$. Thus, the second clause of Definition 1 is equivalent to
$$\forall I\Bigl( (I\triangleleft R)\to \bigl( \neg (M\subseteq I)\vee \neg (M\neq I) \vee \neg (I\neq R)\bigr)\Bigr).$$
We again use the equivalence of $\neg P\wedge Q$ and $P\to Q$; the second clause of Definition 1 is thus equivalent to:
$$\forall I\Bigl( (I\triangleleft R)\to \bigl( (M\subseteq I)\to\bigl(\neg(M\neq I)\vee\neg(I\neq R)\bigr)\bigr)\Bigr).$$
$\neg P\vee \neg Q$ is equivalent to $\neg (P\wedge Q)$ (De Morgan's Law). Thus, the second clause of Definition 1 is equivalent to
$$\forall I\Bigl( (I\triangleleft R)\to\bigl( (M\subseteq I)\to\neg\bigl( M\neq I\wedge I\neq R)\bigr)\bigr)\Bigr).$$
$P\to(Q\to R)$ is equivalent to $(P\wedge Q)\to R$. Thus, the second clause of Definition 1 is equivalent to
$$\forall I\Bigl( \bigl((I\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\subseteq I)\bigr) \to \neg( (M\neq I)\wedge (I\neq R) )\Bigr).$$
From De Morgan's Law again, $\neg( \neg A\wedge \neg B)$ is equivalent to $(A\vee B)$, so the second clause of Definition 1 is equivalent to
$$\forall I\Bigl( \bigl( (I\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\subseteq I)\bigr) \to \bigl( (M=I)\vee (I=R)\bigr)\Bigr),$$
which is precisely the second clause of Definition 2.


$M\lhd R$ means $M$ is an ideal of $R$ or $M$ is a proper ideal of $R$?  Also, in most algebra textbooks, is Definition 2 more commonly used than definition 1, and if students get presented with definition 1, are they expected to figure out for themselves using symbolic logic notation how it is equivalent to definition 2?

@Seth It means "is an ideal of R", which implies that it is contained (not necessarily properly) in $I$. Students are expected to figure out by simple, standard, logic that Definition 1 is equivalent to Definition 2. One says "there is nothing strictly in between"; two says "anything between them must be equal to one of them." YOU are the one who seems to want to do this strictly via symbolic logic, for reasons known only to yourself.

in both Definition 1 and Definition 2 symbolization, $(M\triangleleft R)\wedge (M\neq R)\Bigr)$ is common to both in thte beginning?

@Seth I am translating "proper ideal". I am using symbology that you are insisting you want to use. What is common is to not insist on symbolic manipulation and instead to use common sense and understanding.

when you and Bill told me that I should brush up on my logical reasonsings pertaining to math, I thought you two included these types of sybolic translation exercises.  I got the impression from you two that these types of exercises are suppose to be eventually routine for any students of mathematics and they can do it on the fly on the spot if they needed to.

@Seth These exercises usually happen at the level of an "introduction to proofs" course, at least one (if not two or three) semesters before students begin to learn abstract algebra. By the time someone begins to learn abstract algebra, they better have all of these things down by having studied them before they attempt  abstract algebra. You decided to jump ahead, and now are trying to learn these basics through abstract algebra. Which is unlikely to help you develop an understanding of either.

I think I told you before that when I started my degree in mathematics, I took a theory based Calculus course using Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition text.   The department recommend students to take a course in symbolic logic from the philosophy department. The department bavk then did not have an introduction to proof course.  They had an intro do abstract math based on Courant and Robbins text.  As a matter of fact, if I took the theory based calculus course, I was not allow to take the intro to abstract math course.  The idea is that if i can go through Spivak Calculus, then...

..I am suppose to know how to do proofs.  I have gone through Velleman's How to Prove it Text and most of its exercises.  But I think that is diffferent from actually taking an actual course.  I ended up taking the symbolic logic course,.  That was all my exposure to symbolic logic.  The thing is, many of the intro to proof textbooks, they never require their readers to do a lot of symbolic translations of complicated math definitions.   The examples are very easy and manageble for many beginners.

@Seth "I am supposed to know how to do proofs."  Bully for you; unfortunately, you routinely fail to provide any evidence of actual ability to do so. "I have gone through Velleman's How to Prove It Text and most of its exercises," Again, bully for you; but if what you write here is any indication, this has failed to make any lasting impression or taught you anything lasting about it. Rather, I suspect that this "going through" has taken a similar path as your abstract algebra efforts, where you end up reading a solution, (think you) understand it, but do not actually learn from it.

what does it mean by "bully for you"?  I value both Bill's and your criticism.  I am trying to find a way to improve.  I am learning a lot of this stuff on my own and not in a classroom setting.  The only people I can really ask questions are my friends who are in math and on here. Also, I would do the exercises, and check if the solutions by asking someone to see if I did them correctly.  If I am stuck, not understanding a definition, or a question, I go on here.  If I don't understand a solution, I post them and ask questions here.  I can't be asking questions on here...

..everytime I don't understand something.  I mean I suppose I can, but I would feel really bad for spamming the community everytime I don't understand every little thing.

As is said by Aryuro in the comment, what you mean by $\subset$ is confusing.
For clarity I restate your question first.
In what follows, $A \subseteq B$ means "for all $x\in A$, we have $x\in B$".
$A\subsetneqq B$ means "$A\subseteq B$ and $A\ne B$".
We want to prove: $M$ is an ideal of the ring $R$ and $M\ne R$. Then, there does not exist ideal $I$ s.t. $M\subsetneqq I\subsetneqq R$ $\Leftrightarrow$ if $J$ is an ideal s.t. $M\subseteq J$, then $J=M$ or $J=R$.
Here $I$ and $J$ are "dummy variables". So for clarity I used different letters $I,J$ for ideals in two statements.
Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$   Let $J$ be an ideal s.t. $M\subseteq J$. Assume neither $J=M$ nor $J=R$.
Then $M\subsetneqq J\subsetneqq R$ (since the hypothesis says that $M\subseteq J$, and of course $J\subseteq R$).
This contradicts the hypothesis that there does not exist ideal $I$ s.t. $M\subsetneqq I\subsetneqq R$
(for now $J$ serves a choice of $I$).
$(\Leftarrow)$ Assume exists an ideal $I$ s.t.   $M\subsetneqq I\subsetneqq R$.
Then $M\subseteq I$ since $M\subsetneqq I$, and $I\ne M,R$ since the containment is proper, a contradiction.
